# How to use the "!is.na" function with zoo objects

Tags: r, zoo

I have problems using the `is.na` function with a zoo object. Here is what I tried:

```
z1 <- zoo(matrix(1:8, 4, 2), as.Date("2003-01-01") + 0:3)
z1[2,1]<-NA
```

So, z1 is...

```
2003-01-01  1 5
2003-01-02 NA 6
2003-01-03  3 7
2003-01-04  4 8
```

When I use multiplying a column with `is.na` I get:

```
!is.na(z1[,1])*z1[,2]
```

It returned:

```
2003-01-01 2003-01-02 2003-01-03 2003-01-04 
      TRUE      FALSE       TRUE       TRUE
```

However, when I simply do TRUE*100, the program returns numbers :

```
TRUE*100
[1] 100
FALSE*100
[1] 0
```

What function should I use to have the program returning numbers instead of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s (I'm looking here for the equivalent function of `!is.na` for zoo objects)?

Comment: you should do this `(!is.na(z1[,1])) * z1[,2]`

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried and it works well!

Answer (score 2):

`!` has lower precedence than `*`, so your first example is being parsed as

```
!(is.na(z1[,1]) * z1[,2])
```

See `?Syntax` for operator precedence in R.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your solution and it still returned Trues and Falses. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: The logical `not` has always highest binding priority over all other logical operators. However, as a general rule you can note that mathematical operators have even higher priority than logical operators.